# Is there a way to sort SPARQL query results by relevance score in MarkLogic 8?

Tags: sparql, marklogic

We're running SPARQL queries on some clinical ontology data in our MarkLogic server. Our queries look like the following:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX cts: <http://marklogic.com/cts#>

SELECT *
FROM <http://example/ontologies/snomedct>
WHERE {
  ?s rdfs:label ?o .
  FILTER cts:contains(?o, cts:word-query("Smoke*", "wildcarded"))
}
LIMIT 10
```

We expected to get sorted results based off of relevance score, but instead  they seemed to be in some random order. Tried many ways with the query but nothing worked. After some research we found this statement in the MarkLogic docs:

> When understanding the order an expression returns in, there are two
>   main rules to consider:
>
> - cts:search expressions always return in relevance order (the most    relevant to the least relevant).
> - XPath expressions always return in document order.

Does this mean that cts:contains is a XPath expression that always return in document order? If that's the case, how can we construct a SPARQL query that returns in relevance order?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: `cts:search` is for XQuery and not for SPARQL

Comment: @AKSW, I see. It'd be very nice if MarkLogic had a way to rank query results in pure SPARQL.

Answer (score 3):

In the example you have, the language you are using is SPARQL - with a fragment filter of the cts:contains.

IN this case, the cts:contains is only useful in isolating fragment IDs that match - thus filtering the candidate documents used in the SPARQL query. Therefore, I do not believe that the the cts relevance is taken into account.

However, you could possibly get results you are looking for in a different way: Do an actual cts:search on the documents in question - then filter them using a cts:triple-range-query.

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:triple-range-query

Comment: Thanks, David. Do you know if it's possible to use cts:search in a SPARQL query? We're trying to make it pure SPARQL because there's code we can reuse.

Comment: hi. not  a full cts search. just anything that returns a cts-query  - which is essentially a filter on the fragments that include triples